# how to get wishlist id according to the product id?

Tags: wishlist

I have a product id but i want to know the wishlist id according to that product id. 
Is there any way to find that wish list corresponding that productid?

Comment: your question is unable to understand please specify in detail.

Comment: is there any way  to get wishlist id according to the product id?

Comment: Give you update.

Comment: Get by customer?

Comment: no get by product_id

Comment: $wishlist_id=Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$collection1['entity_id']); I am using this code i want to add wishlist_id in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$productId =1;
$wishlistItem = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$productId);
if(count($wishlistItem)) {
    $wishlistIds = $wishlistItem->getColumnValues('wishlist_id');
    print_r($wishlistIds);
}


//OR

if(count($wishlistItem)) {
    echo $wishlistId = $wishlistItem->getFirstItem()->getWishlistId();
}
```

Comment: i am already using this is there any way to get wishlist id without using foreach

Comment: update ans pls check now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to fully understand the question but there is no function to get all wishlist IDs linked to a product.
The way to do that is make a query in `wishlist_item` table.
For example : `SELECT wishlist_id FROM wishlist_item WHERE product_id = {your_product_id}`
Or if you want in a Magento way :
`$adapter    = $this->_getReadAdapter();
$select     = $adapter->select()->from($this->getTable('wishlist/item'), array('product_id'))->where('product_id=:product_id');
$bind       = array(
    'product_id' => $productId
);
$data       = $adapter->fetchRow($select, $bind);`
Edit with you example :
`$wishlistIds = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$collection1['entity_id'])->getAllIds();`

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: I am using this $wishlist_id=Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$collection1['entity_id']);

Comment: And i want wishist id

Comment: add a `->getFirstItem()`at the end of you collection

Comment: first ite give me wishlist ids for corresponding that product id?

Comment: `->getFirstItem()` give you the first item of you collection. `->getAllIds()` give you all IDs as an array